# Google-Hire > Candidates List filter parameter doesn't work

Tags: google-api

We're Working with **Google Hire** We're trying to apply filter param in the request to candidates list endpoint, using one field as **email** for example:

```
        const response = await hire.tenants.candidates.list({
            auth: oauth2client,
            parent: 'tenants/my_tenant',
            filter: 'email=candidate@mail.co'
        });
```

We're tried another ways for filter as:

```
filter: 'email="candidate@mail.co"'
filter: 'candidates.email=candidate@mail.co'
filter: 'candidates.email="candidate@mail.co"'
filter: 'candidate.email=candidate@mail.co'
etc..
```

But always get an error, details for it is:

```
  "code": 400,
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "badRequest"
            }
        ]
```

Documentation > https://developers.google.com/hire/tenants/rest/v1beta1/tenants.candidates/list?authuser=1

Anyone had it or similar issue using hire or another google-api?

Thank in advance!